# Python, mongodb дата в UTC и выборка по local timezone

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, timezone

Я записываю данные в базу с датой в UTC. 
затем я применяю подобную выборку.

```
    today = db.data.find({
    "sentDate": {
        '$gte': "%s 00:00:00"%today_date,
        '$lt':  "%s 23:59:59"%today_date
    }
})
```

Естественно в выборке при этом присутствуют расхождения, так как мой часовой пояс от UTC отличается на 3 часа

как в данной ситуации можно учитывать часовой пояс?

```
now = datetime.utcnow()
today_date = datetime.strftime(now,"%Y-%m-%d")
week_date = datetime.strftime(now - timedelta(days=6),"%Y-%m-%d")
month_date = datetime.strftime(now - timedelta(days=29),"%Y-%m-%d")
year_date = datetime.strftime(now - timedelta(days=365),"%Y-%m-%d")

today = db.data.find({
    "sentDate": {
        '$gte': "%s 00:00:00"%today_date,
        '$lt':  "%s 23:59:59"%today_date
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

требует Python 3.2+

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

рабоатет в 2.7 и 3.2 ветках

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

Comment: не не пойдет, я же хочу выводить это по своему часовому поясу

Comment: @JohnDoe, Alex78191 показал как получить текущее время в UTC. Попробуйте: `datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`

Comment: перевод даты в UTC должен помочь мне выбрать данные по дням, неделям и т.д  по моему часовому поясу? я дополнил пост куском кода, где я фильтрую записи по utc дате. Никаких изменений

Comment: @JohnDoe вы и так по UTC получали. Если хотите отображать время во времени вашего часового пояса, то конвертируйте время после получения из бд. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111317/how-do-i-print-a-python-datetime-in-the-local-timezone

Comment: бред. мне нужно достать объекты какие вписываются во временные рамки по моему часовому поясу. а выводить дату в нужной локали это  уже дело десятое

Comment: @JohnDoe вместо datetime.utcnow получайте datetime.now и потом результат расчета конца дня по вашему времени конвертируйте в UTC.

Comment: да так сойдет, спасибо

Comment: @JohnDoe Напишите ответ как сделаете